# Using both baseurl and mirrorlist in yum.repo

Tags: centos, yum, repository, nexus

I want to cache RPM packets in my Nexus Repository. In repo file on client side I have two lines, both uncommented:

```
baseurl=http://nexus-ip/repository/bts-nexus-almalinux-base/$releasever/BaseOS/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.almalinux.org/mirrorlist/$releasever/baseos
```

Yum updates goes only to mirrorlist. If I comment mirrorlist, then everything working fine, but if nexus repo unavailable, then servers can't update packets. What I want in the end, that client goes first to baseurl and only if it's unavailable, uses mirrorlist. Is it possible? How can I prioritise baseurl over mirrorlist?

Answer (score 0):

`mirrorlist` is just to give you more alternatives to download packages, from doc.

> mirrorlist Specifies a URL to a file containing a list of baseurls.
> This can be used instead of or with the baseurl option. Substitution
> variables, described below, can be used with this option. As a special
> hack is the mirrorlist URL contains the word "metalink" then the value
> of mirrorlist is copied to metalink (if metalink is not set).

So you can put same `baseurl` in top of the `mirrorlist` and survive only with mirrorlist incase some packages are not part of `baseurl` url.

Edit 1:

You can try baseurl and `failovermethod=priority` combination, add urls based in priority you want in similar sequence.

> failovermethod
>
> It can be 'roundrobin' or 'priority'. 'roundrobin' randomly selects a URL from the list of URLs to start and then if it
> failes to contact the selected server it proceed with another selected
> similarly. 'priority' starts from the first one listed in baseurl and
> if it fails to contact the server, it continues sequentially with the
> next in the list. If not specified, the default is 'priority'.It can be 'roundrobin' or 'priority'. 'roundrobin'

You can give multiple baseurl like below,

```
baseurl=http://<service_node>/install/centos7.5/x86_64         
        http://<master_node>/install/centos7.5/x86_64
```

Comment: How to set the priority to use the baseurl, then the mirrorlist? I tried using `failovermethod` in .repo file, seems not working tho.

Comment: Updated my answer,